# Rank a column based on 2 conditions in pandas

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements, rank

I have a df as such

`df
   col_a  col_b
0     ADD     5
1     ADD     2
2     ADD     8
3     DELETE  3
4     DELETE  7
5     DELETE  4`

now i want to rank the values in col_b when col_a = ADD and then rank the values in col_b where col_a = DELETE. So have two separate rank values but within one column. i have the code which ranks based on one condition but can some help me with two conditions. thanks

```
df['Rank'] = df.col_b[df['col_a'] == 'ADD'].rank()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df.groupby().rank()`

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby('col_a')['col_b'].rank()
```